# DXL ole objects binary stream

Tags: rtf, ole, ibm-doors

I have issues importing ole objects in doors. 
I received an RIF file (zip with xml and OLE folder).
when I import the document excel table, word files and pictures are embedded as ole objects. 
These documents are imported as *.ole files, and are not showed even if embedded in the code.

the ole files have this kind of headers:

```
{\object\objemb{\*\objclass Excel.Sheet.12}\objw488745\objh2055{\*\objdata

{\object\objemb{\*\objclass Word.Document.12}\objw9308\objh3666{\*\objdata 

{\pict\wmetafile8\picw15121\pich22138\picwgoal8528\pichgoal12506
```

I wrote a simple wrapper that is able to extract word data and xlsx and wmf in our os, but: 
xlsx documents are "corrupted" and can't be imported in doors.

To override this issue I would like to be able to import the native ole object into the doors module, but I can't find any viable method.

I tried to append an rtf header to the document, like:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 
Tahoma;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20
```

but still I am not able to embed the document in the object.

I also tried with a simple dxl script but no luck:

```
Object o = current;
oleInsert(o, o."Object Text", "C:/Doors/asd.rtf", false)
```

Any hint would be gladly appreciated.
I can provide more details if required.

K.R.

Answer (score 0):

K.R. not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but it sounds like you are able to successfully extract the RTF code for the OLE object but just have no idea how to import it into DOORS?

`oleInsert` attempts to place the actual file not the RTF code from the file into the Object.

If you're just trying to assign the richtext to the object text you can try something like this:

```
Object o = current;
string oleString = (...) //assign to RTF code you parsed out for individual ole object
o."Object Text" = richText(oleString)
```